# Error When using 'ng generate component' for Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an `Angular 4` project which at first I was able to use the `ng generate component` command but since I have implemented `Routing` the command no longer works as I get the following error

> Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
>   More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

I'm not too sure if its the `Routing` that is causing this but that's all I can seem to put my finger on and I need to get it fixed

Comment: You can tell angular which module would you wan to add the newly component by `ng g c newComponent --module targetModuleName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error speaks for itself, as you have at least two modules in your project. You need to use the skip-import flag because Angular is unable to decide for what module it should be imported. After you added the skip-import flag, the error will be gone. But you will have to manually import the component into the module you wish to utilize it in.

Like this:

`ng generate component newComponent --skip-import`

Comment: I haven't already got the module though as I checked. First thing I did was to check. I tired creating one using 'abcdefantony' (very unique) but still got the above error

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `ng g component ComponentName` inside the module folder.

Comment: tried but still get the error.  File name I was using has not been used before as I was trying to use the following `ng g component four0four`

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me using VS 2017 on Windows 10 with @angular/cli (6.0.8):

ng g c components/name-component ---module ../app/app.shared.module.ts

And run this command from ...\ClientApp\app